# Remove phone number from Expo XDE

Tags: react-native, expo

Is it possible to remove a phone number from the "Share" menu? Expo XDE is sending out a link every time a new version is published and I cannot get it to stop. I've tried:

- Deleting the phone number, it fills back in
- Changing the phone number to all 0's
- Re-launching Expo XDE

Comment: I tried to tag this with XDE but I don't have enough rep. If someone else could add that tag, that would be great!

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/678 there is a closed issue there. Maybe updating?